# Show "Unseen" & "modal" dialog - javascript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I want to show the "unseen" "modal" dialog in javascript. 
This sounds weird, but, I want the effect of "modal" dialog, which is to make the background uncontrollable & shadow color. But, I don't want to show the dialog popup window.
So, I thought if I can do this by showing "unseen", "modal" dialog.
Is this possible?

I cannot find a similar question & good properties of dialog which can do what I want.

Comment: You can just make a transparent element that covers the entire page.

Comment: But, if I do that, I feel entire page become something like white?? I want to do something like putting shadow cover on the entire page. And, "uncontrollable" is important

Comment: So make it transparent. What does `uncontrollable` mean?

Comment: Sorry, I understood. So, Maybe I can use "overlay". "uncontrollable" means if we popup "modal" dialog, users cannot click some buttons behind the shadow screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without creating the modal by adding a div that is the height and width of the page and positioning it on top: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2cuRX/

```
$(function () {
    $('#overlayBtn').on('click', function () {
        $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
        $("#overlay").height($(document).height())
            .css({
            'opacity': 0.4,
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': 0,
                'left': 0,
                'background-color': 'black',
                'width': '100%',
                'z-index': 5000
        });
    });
});
```